# Can I run two or more flow files at once on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I know that inside the file `settings.js` there's a variable called `flows.json` and I can set it to run different flows. And I also know that when the projects feature is enabled I can switch between entire flow files. However, it seems that one flow stops running when I change my flow. Is it possible to run two different flow files at once using Node-RED?

I understand the asynchronous nature of Javascript and that if I develop synchronous code on my flow it'll stop all the other nodes too... I'm just curious if I'm limited to work with one flow file at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, only one flow file can be loaded at a time.

If you want to run multiple independent flows files then you will have to run separate instances, this can be done by changing the port the instance runs on.

As well as changing the flow file in the `settings.js` file you can also add it to the end of the command line used to start the instance.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already running two different instances on two different ports... I just started wondering if I was missing some different way of doing it.